# nodemailer is sending all previously sent addresses as cc

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer 2.4.2. It is working fine and sending emails with no errors.
However now it is running on the live site, it is progressively adding all the previous addresses to each email. I have added  a transport.close() now, but the documentation seems to suggest that this is an efficiency measure and not for this problem. The script is not accessing the tables and so can only be collecting the addresses from cache

Comment: Sounds very much like you forgot to properly declare a variable, promoting it to a global.

Comment: share the part of the code where you send the mail

Comment: I was collecting an array stored in the serverConfig, containing two emails. Then pushing the email entered in the form before sending the list.
I didn't realise that I was then using a reference to the original, which meant the list was being added to constantly.
Now using the dot dot dot notation to make a copy, it seems to have fixed the problem.

const sendToList = serverConfig.emailAddresses;
and Now
const sendToList = [...serverConfig.emailAddresses];

  sendToList.push(email);

Answer (score 0):

I was collecting an array stored in the serverConfig, containing two emails. Then pushing the email entered in the form before sending the list
I didn't realise that I was then using a reference to the original, which meant the list was being added to constantly.
Now using the dot dot dot notation to make a copy, it seems to have fixed the problem.
    const sendToList = serverConfig.emailAddresses;
and Now
    const sendToList = [...serverConfig.emailAddresses];

sendToList.push(email);